# Using SingleChildScrollview inside Column widget content is not scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              fit: StackFit.loose,
              children: <Widget>[
                HeadersVC(),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_back,
                          size: 30,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        widget.headertitleladderPre,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  ),
                  //******************************************** Date Picker  */
                  TextFormField(
                    onTap: () async {
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                      _selectDate(context);
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide:
                                BorderSide(color: Colors.black26, width: 1.5)),
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0),
                        labelText: formatDate(formatedDate),
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black),
                        suffixIcon: new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 0.0, left: 0.0, right: 0.0, bottom: 0.0),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: 15,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.calendar_today,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, top: 10.0),
                  ),
                  //******************************************** DropDown Button  */
                  Container(
                    child: DropdownButton(
                      underline: Container(
                        height: 1.0,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border(
                                bottom: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black26, width: 1.5))),
                      ),
                      value: _selectedladleno,
                      items: _dropDownladleItems,
                      onChanged: changedDropDownItem,
                      isExpanded: true,
                      isDense: false,
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                      iconSize: 30,
                      elevation: 12,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  //******************************************** Radio Button  */
                  ButtonBar(
                    alignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    buttonPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Radio(
                        groupValue: _character,
                        onChanged: (SingingCharacter value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _character = value;
                            print(_character);
                          });
                        },
                        value: SingingCharacter.New,
                        activeColor: Colors.red,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "New",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
                      ),
                      Radio(
                        groupValue: _character,
                        onChanged: (SingingCharacter value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _character = value;
                            print(_character);
                          });
                        },
                        value: SingingCharacter.Repair,
                        activeColor: Colors.red,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Repair",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
                      ),
                      Radio(
                        groupValue: _character,
                        onChanged: (SingingCharacter value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _character = value;
                            print(_character.toString());
                          });
                        },
                        value: SingingCharacter.OnlyMachineChange,
                        activeColor: Colors.red,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Machine Change",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  //******************************************** Machine Number  */
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Machine Number *",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I got Error Something Like this :

Performing hot reload...                                               ⣟flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown during layout:
flutter: A RenderFlex overflowed by 158 pixels on the bottom.
flutter:
flutter: The relevant error-causing widget was:
flutter:   Column file:///Users/baps/Projects/Flutter%20Projects/TRLApp/trlapp/lib/ladlePreheating.dart:64:16
flutter:
flutter: The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
flutter: The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
flutter: black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
flutter: Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
flutter: RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
flutter: This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
flutter: seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
flutter: ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
flutter: like a ListView.
flutter: The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#4bdfd relayoutBoundary=up1 OVERFLOWING:
flutter:   needs compositing
flutter:   creator: Column ← Container ← _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ←
flutter:     CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ←
flutter:     _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#9c17c ink renderer] ← NotificationListener ←
flutter:     PhysicalModel ← ⋯
flutter:   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body (can use size)
flutter:   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=414.0, 0.0<=h<=736.0)
flutter:   size: Size(414.0, 736.0)
flutter:   direction: vertical
flutter:   mainAxisAlignment: start
flutter:   mainAxisSize: max
flutter:   crossAxisAlignment: center
flutter:   verticalDirection: down
flutter: ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Comment: Did you try a hot restart?

Comment: Also please remove the title bar or stack widget in column widget, you can added in appbar it self. even if it's customized.

Answer (score 27):

Missed to Expand the ScrollView as Column container would not know how much space it needs to take and due to that, it calculates the size which is more than of screen size.

So Just place Expanded in to it:

```
...
Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  padding:...
```

[image: output]

Comment: Your welcome, mark as done, else question will remain open.

Comment: Dear i am getting error; RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#6ba10 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Comment: Explain your issue @Kamlesh, or add another question, I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

`SingleChildScrollView` should be Wrapped around `Column`:

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: Container(
    child: SingleChildScrollView( // <--- Put it here.
        child: Column( // <--- Your Column.
```

Comment: Yes, it can but that first stack container contains his appbar or something like that...

Comment: Appbar is a part of scaffold.

Comment: Yah, That I know but for some reason, he added in the column. strange though.

Comment: Wrong code gives wrong output, ideally it should be in scaffold. if is is in column the code needs to be changed and SingleChildScrollView should be used the way I have mentioned in answer.

Comment: yup, it's true, might be a beginner in flutter so might not come to know all the features available in it.

Comment: Can you please accept and up-vote the answer if the solution is working for you ??

Comment: Getting error: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#6ba10 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Answer (score 0):

Solution: You need to use SingleChildScrollView before column .If you want to keep separated stack part ,you can use CustomScrollView . [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html)

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              fit: StackFit.loose,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_back,
                          size: 30,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "headertitleladderPre",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            ),
            //******************************************** Date Picker  */
            TextFormField(
              onTap: () async {},
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(color: Colors.black26, width: 1.5)),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0),
                  labelText: "formatedDate",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black),
                  suffixIcon: new Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 0.0, left: 0.0, right: 0.0, bottom: 0.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.calendar_today,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, top: 10.0),
            ),
            //******************************************** DropDown Button  */
            Container(
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                value: dropdownValue,
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                iconSize: 24,
                elevation: 16,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                underline: Container(
                  height: 2,
                  color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                ),
                onChanged: (String newValue) {},
                items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
                    .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
            //******************************************** Radio Button  */
            ButtonBar(
              alignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              buttonPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Radio Here"),
                Text(
                  "New",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
                ),
                Text("One More Radio Here"),
                Text(
                  "Repair",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
                ),
                Text("One More Radio Here"),
                Text(
                  "Machine Change",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            //******************************************** Machine Number  */
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Machine Number *",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Well Block Party *",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black)),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Avoid Using

**child: ConstrainedBox(
constraints: BoxConstraints()),**

In side SingleChildScrollView when i remove this widget rendering error is gone.

Sample Code of my layout.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kBackgroundColorGray,
      appBar: commonAppBar,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [

             ],
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
```